# curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, github, curl, proxy

I would like to install nvm on my Linux computer.
(My Debian version is 10.)

I read this document https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script
and I input this script.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

This is the result.

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I read this document https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html but I could not understand what to do. Therefore, I searched the Internet and found that I need proxy configuration.

```
export http_proxy="http://webfilter.**********.com:8000/"
export https_proxy="http://webfilter.**********.com:8000/"
```

I entered these commands in my terminal and tried this script again.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

Then I get the same result.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

How can can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

> found that I need proxy configuration.

Check first if you did need any proxy before that call.
[For instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47794689/6309) (without proxy exported):

```
curl -Is http://www.google.com | head -1 | grep 200; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then; echo "Online"; else; echo "Offline"; fi
```

If that works, then the issue is different.
If not, try again with your proxy in place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I copy and paste on my terminal, and get this message. ```bash: unexpected token `;' syntax error```  Could you help me please?

Comment: @KazuakiSuzuki Then simplify first, and test with just `curl -Is http://www.google.com | head -1 | grep 200`

Comment: I get ```HTTP/1.1 200 OK```

Comment: @KazuakiSuzuki That means you don't need proxy in your case.

Comment: Really!!!! Could you tell me how can I find my problem, please?

Comment: @KazuakiSuzuki Can you check if you have the openssl package installed? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57885621/6309)

Comment: ```OpenSSL> version   OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019``` openssl is installed.

Comment: @KazuakiSuzuki What is you version of Git, and what does `git config -l` return? Anything relate to `http.sslXXX`? (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpsslCert) I mentioned `http.sslCAinfo` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35824116/6309.

Comment: ```git version 2.20.1``` ```git config -l``` command returns nothing.

Comment: Does this mean I need git configuration?

Comment: Now I understand that I should write something in ~/.gitconfig

Comment: @KazuakiSuzuki Possibly, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35824116/6309 (reinstalling ca-certificate is a good tip). But upgrading Git to 2.27 (or at least 2.26.2) would be also sensible, to check if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I am trying. Just a moment please.

Comment: I am reinstalling git now. I will try ca-certificate tomorrow. I am glad if you could help me tomorrow. Thank you so much!

Comment: I tried stackoverflow.com/a/35824116/6309 . ```sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates``` and ```sudo mkdir /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org``` worked. However, ```sudo wget -P /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org http://www.cacert.org/certs/root.crt http://www.cacert.org/certs/class3.crt``` didnt work. I got ```connecting to www.cacert.org (www.cacert.org)|213.154.225.245|:80 ... failed : connection is timed out``` Could you tell me what to do please?

Comment: @KazuakiSuzuki Please see https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215139/discussion-between-kazuaki-suzuki-and-vonc